# Unable to cast object of type [" "] to type

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I need some help with this error. I know it's probably self-explanatory, but I'm kind of new to web and just need some help!

`Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[QuestionnaireUserAnswer]' to type 'QuestionnaireUserAnswer'.`

Line the exception is thrown on:

```
return (QuestionnaireUserAnswer)Session["SFS_QuestionnaireAnswer_Detail_" + questionnaireId];
```

Comment: please show your code ..

Comment: please post your code and the line that you get the exception. It's

Comment: well, you simply can't cast `List<T>` to `T`. Consider casting to `IEnumerable<QuestionnaireUserAnswer>` and then use `First` `Single` or any other aggregation methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to cast it like

```
return (List<QuestionnaireUserAnswer>)Session["SFS_QuestionnaireAnswer_Detail_" + questionnaireId];
```

Comment: he probably has `QuestionnaireUserAnswer` as a return type. Not expecting to see `object` as return type

Comment: I think he is binding List<QuestionnaireUserAnswer> into the session, and trying to retrieve it back

Answer (score 0):

Cast the item to a list

```
(Item as List<Expoint.Business.QuestionnaireUserAnswer>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your return type should be `List<QuestionnaireUserAnswer>`. Use as below.

```
return (List<QuestionnaireUserAnswer>)Session["SFS_QuestionnaireAnswer_Detail_" + questionnaireId];
```